# find a max in nested list with a same first element

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> a
[[1990, 51.3096170908506], [1992, 51.2635305924819], [1992, 51.3374119057099], [1992, 51.8759788779255], [1993, 51.1736475226503], [1993, 51.2227948371244], [1993, 51.2227948371244], [1993, 51.8494182515316], [1993, 51.8494182515316], [1994, 51.1741251939274], [1994, 51.88740455961], [1995, 51.1782277553216], [1996, 50.8955164985205], [1996, 50.8955164985205], [1996, 51.1376528237266], [1996, 51.1740979454], [1997, 50.8955819858876], [1997, 50.8983272540453], [1997, 51.8619829641787], [1997, 51.8619829641787]]
```

how to find the maximum latitude of each year (python):
for example:

```
[1992, 51.8759788779255]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict(list)` to create a dictionary that contains the latitudes grouped by year:

```
>>> import collections
>>> result = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in data:
...     result[item[0]].append(item[1])
...
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1990: [51.3096170908506], 1992: [51.2635305924819, 51.3374119057099, 51.8759788779255], 1993: [51.1736475226503, 51.2227948371244, 51.2227948371244, 51.8494182515316, 51.8494182515316], 1994: [51.1741251939274, 51.88740455961], 1995: [51.1782277553216], 1996: [50.8955164985205, 50.8955164985205, 51.1376528237266, 51.1740979454], 1997: [50.8955819858876, 50.8983272540453, 51.8619829641787, 51.8619829641787]})
>>> for key, value in result.items():
...     print key, max(value)
...
1990 51.3096170909
1992 51.8759788779
1993 51.8494182515
1994 51.8874045596
1995 51.1782277553
1996 51.1740979454
1997 51.8619829642
```

This dictionary has the year as keys and the latitudes in a list as the values. You can then iterate over the contents of that dictionary and use `max()` to get the maximum latitude within all latitudes of that year.

Comment: Thank you! is there any way that i can create this dictionary(result) without using "collections"?

Comment: @AnahitaKp: yes, in that case you use a regular dictionary and you'll need to build up the dictionary yourself by adding the key/values accordingly. So that means: when the key isn't in the dictionary yet, add the key and as value with one latitude and, in case the key is indeed in the dictionary, then you append it to the existing list that's already there for that key.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you don't want to use collections.defaultdict, you have to provide the initial value with dict.setdefault:

```
a = [[1990, 51.3096170908506], [1992, 51.2635305924819],
     [1992, 51.3374119057099], [1992, 51.8759788779255],
     [1993, 51.1736475226503], [1993, 51.2227948371244],
     [1993, 51.2227948371244], [1993, 51.8494182515316],
     [1993, 51.8494182515316], [1994, 51.1741251939274],
     [1994, 51.88740455961], [1995, 51.1782277553216],
     [1996, 50.8955164985205], [1996, 50.8955164985205],
     [1996, 51.1376528237266], [1996, 51.1740979454],
     [1997, 50.8955819858876], [1997, 50.8983272540453],
     [1997, 51.8619829641787], [1997, 51.8619829641787]]

result = {}

for year, lat in a:
    result.setdefault(year, []).append(lat)

for year in result:
    print(year, max(result[year]))

'''
1990 51.3096170908506
1992 51.8759788779255
1993 51.8494182515316
1994 51.88740455961
1995 51.1782277553216
1996 51.1740979454
1997 51.8619829641787
'''
```

Comment: thanks, how the final output(year and max) can be in another list or dic?

Answer (score 0):

Can i try this way:

```
 >>> [sorted(x, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0] for x in [[(y[0],y[1]) for y in a if y[0]==x] for x in values]]
    [(1990, 51.3096170908506), 
    (1992, 51.8759788779255), 
    (1993, 51.8494182515316), 
    (1994, 51.88740455961), 
    (1995, 51.1782277553216), 
    (1996, 51.1740979454), 
    (1997, 51.8619829641787)]
>>>
```